# UITabBarItem Image is in Blue and not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Um using my own `TabBarController` which is `ElWafyatTabBarController` basically it inherits from `UITabBarController`.

In `ElWafyatTabBarController.m -> viewDidLoad`

I've created some `ViewControllers`, Then I created `UINavigationController`'s with rootViewController to the `viewControllers` I've made in the step before.

then I've created `UITabBarItem` and set it with image and title for each navigation controller which has `rootViewController` to the viewControllers that I've created in the first step, and set the `tabBarItem` for these `navigationController` to these `tabBarItem`.

The problem I found is even the title for the `UITabBarItem` is shown correctly, but the image is displayed at blue Color.

FYI: I've created two images named test.png and test@2x.png with dimensions 32x32 and 64x64
and I still have these issue,
So any one can help ?

this is my Code:

ElWafyatTabBarController -> viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    NaaiViewController *naaiViewController = [[NaaiViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"NaaiViewController" bundle:nil];
    MushatraViewController *mushatraViewController = [[MushatraViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"MushatraViewController" bundle:nil];
    TakremViewController *takremViewController = [[TakremViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"TakremViewController" bundle:nil]
    UINavigationController *homeNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
    UINavigationController *naaiNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:naaiViewController];
    UINavigationController *mushatraNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mushatraViewController];
    UINavigationController *takremNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:takremViewController];

    // Setup Controllers for Tab Bar. (first level).
//    [homeNavC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"الرئيسية"];
//    [naaiNavC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"نعي"];
//    [mushatraNavC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"مشاطرة"];
//    [takremNavC.tabBarItem setTitle:@"تكريم"];

    homeNavC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    naaiNavC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    mushatraNavC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    takremNavC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];

    homeNavC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    naaiNavC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    mushatraNavC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    takremNavC.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    UITabBarItem* tabBarItem =  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Colors" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] tag:9];

    homeNavC.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;

    myViewControllers = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects:takremNavC, mushatraNavC, naaiNavC, homeNavC,nil];
    [self setViewControllers:myViewControllers animated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
    [self setSelectedIndex:3];
}
```

and these the output:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to see your image, you need to set the image's rendering mode to `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`, otherwise the image is displayed as a template image. You should read the documentation on tab bars, it has this statement:

> Tab Bar Item Icons
>
> Each item in a tab bar can have a custom selected image and unselected
>   image. You can specify these images when you initialize a tab bar item
>   using the initWithTitle:image:selectedImage: method. Note that a tab
>   bar item image will be automatically rendered as a template image
>   within a tab bar, unless you explicitly set its rendering mode to
>   UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. For more information, see Template
>   Images.

Comment: don't forget that UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal only Available in iOS 7.0 and later

Comment: How/where do you set UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal?

Comment: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

Answer (score 10):

Go to `Assets.xcassets > Click on you image > Attribute Inspector > Render As > Original Image`

[image: original image]

Answer (score 1):

Blue is the default tint color for UITabbar in iOS 7. You can change it to whatever color you like by setting:

```
myTabbar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //Put the color of your choice
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have UITabBar:

```
 UITabBar *tabBar = _tabBarController.tabBar;

 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
```

set the image of **tabBarItem1** like this :

```
 [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected_your_image"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UNSelected_your_image"]];
```

set selected and unselectedimage every UITabBarItem(s) of UITabBar.